# How to set some action in generated buttons inside custom Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, onclicklistener

I got the following composition:

[image]

This layout is an Item of my `RecyclerView.Adapter`. The X button (`holder.delete_button`), when clicked, deletes himself and the `EditText`; basically it removes the row.

The ADD FIELD button add new rows (by inflater):

[image]

Here's the code to add new line:

```
  holder.add_field_button.setOnClickListener {
      holder.parent_layout.apply {
          val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
          val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generated_layout, this, false)
          holder.parent_layout.addView(rowView, holder.parent_layout.childCount!! - 0)
      }
  }
```

My problem here is that **I just can delete the first row**, because is the only `button` I can initialize in the `ViewHolder` by the `id` of `delete_button`. **But for the next X buttons, I can't do no action**, because the button it's in an external layout inflated, called `generated_layout`! I've tried to generate ids but then I don't know how to put them into an array. Here's the code to delete a row:

```
holder.delete_button.setOnClickListener{
    holder.parent_layout.removeView(holder.delete_button.parent as View)
}
```

Here's the code of generated_layout, as well:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:inputType="phone"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the onClick listener like this

```
holder.add_field_button.setOnClickListener {
      holder.parent_layout.apply {
          val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
          val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generated_layout, this, false)
          val rowViewDeleteButton=rowView.findViewById(R.id.deletebutton)
          rowViewDeleteButton.setOnClickListener{
            holder.parent_layout.removeView(it.parent as View)
          }

          holder.parent_layout.addView(rowView, holder.parent_layout.childCount!! - 0)
      }
  }
```

And give `id` to your delete button :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:inputType="phone"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/deletebutton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>
</LinearLayout>
```